# Dataset schema exceeds the maximum length of 65535 in mlflow

Tags: mlflow

Hello I would like to know if it is possible to avoid this error "mlflow.exceptions.MlflowException: Dataset schema exceeds the maximum length of 65535" during mlflow.evaluate. The code works ok with other dataset. I am not interesting to log the dataset. Thanks

````
eval_data = Xtest_
targets = y_test.values

with mlflow.start_run() as run:
    model_info = mlflow.sklearn.log_model(loaded_model, "model")
    result = mlflow.evaluate(
        model_info.model_uri,
        eval_data,
        targets=targets,
        model_type="classifier",
        dataset_name="chase_response_model",
        evaluators=["default"],
    )```
````